# How to run a command with an environment variable? ( solana validator)

Tags: solana

When I run the command : solana-test-validator
I got the following result.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjnsT.png)

I don't know what the last line( note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace) mean.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here.

First, to run a command with an environment variable, you can simply define it before running your command, so in this case:

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 solana-test-validator
```

Second, regarding the specific Solana problem, this is an issue in the recent release, v1.7.9.  Try rolling back to the previous Solana SDK, v1.7.8, by running:

```
solana-install init 1.7.8
```